# How can I input everything under current directory into executable by Windows batch(cmd)?

Tags: windows, opencv, batch-file, cmd, jpeg

I'm a newbie using Windows cmd batch to run my OpenCV executable.

I wish to do this:
I had successfully created an executable under current directory (myImgProc.exe). I have several **arbitrarily named** JPEG files that need to be inputted into myImgProc.exe. By brute-force method, I could write the .bat file as following:

```
    @ECHO OFF
    ECHO Start running myImgProc.exe on JPEG files

    START myImgProc.exe abc_01.jpg
    START myImgProc.exe def_02.jpg
    START myImgProc.exe ert-01.jpg
    START myImgProc.exe tyh-04.jpg
    ...
```

But this is too exhaustive to do because I have at least thousands of JPEG files!

Is there a better way to do it?
Like, how to tell the Windows to find every JPEG file under current directory and set them as the arguments of cmd?

Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
pushd "myStartFolder"
for %%i in (*.jpg) do START "" "myImgProc.exe" "%%~i"
popd
```